# Call to undefined method Closure::group() in Lumen

Tags: php, vue.js, lumen

New to Lumen Vuejs here.

I have a problem regarding the connection between 2 frameworks particularly to generating tokens.

This is my App.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class,
    palanik\lumen\Middleware\LumenCors::class
]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
   'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   'cors' => palanik\lumen\Middleware\LumenCors::class,
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

and this is my AuthServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Boot the authentication services for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Here you may define how you wish users to be authenticated for your Lumen
        // application. The callback which receives the incoming request instance
        // should return either a User instance or null. You're free to obtain
        // the User instance via an API token or any other method necessary.

        // Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport::routes($app);
        LumenPassport::routes();

        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if ($request->input('api_token')) {
                return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is found on the AuthServiceProvider.php file. I have used this package `https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport` for passport, and `https://github.com/palanik/lumen-cors` for cross origin of HTTP requests and i have no idea where is the error is really happening even if i am properly following the documentations of 2 packages has been done exactly.

Your response is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You probably use Lumen 5.5.

`dusterio\lumen-passport` is currently NOT compatible with Lumen 5.5 (as per 5 oct 2017) (see https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport/pull/53)

Either downgrade to Lumen 5.4 or wait for this package to be updated.

Comment: Any idea how can i implement your changes into my project ? Preferably via composer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open AuthServiceProvider.php in your app/Providers folder, add

   ```
   use Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport;
   ```
2. Inside the boot() function, add:

   ```
   LumenPassport::routes($this->app->router, ['prefix' => 'v1/oauth']);
   ```

If you do not want prefix then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution.

Call -

```
   Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport::routes($app);
```

in **bootstrap/app.php** after registering Passport service providers rather than calling *LumenPassport::routes();* in AppServiceProvider as defined in docs.

Then, go to -

```
   <app_source>/vendor/dusterio/lumen-passport/src/LumenPassport.php
```

Search for **routes** function

```
   public static function routes($callback = null, array $options = [])
   {
      ...
   }
```

Look for -

```
   $callback->group($options, function ($router) use ($callback) {
        ...
    });
```

Change -

```
    $callback->group(...) to $callback->route->group(...)
```

That solves the issue completely.

Comment: That is not the correct solution. You should not modify any vendor files. Either there is a problem in vendor/dusterio/lumen-passport and you should submit a bug to the package maintainer or the issue is in your project.

Comment: Definitely. I'll do that. For instance, we can continue with the solution though.

Comment: Hello Vaishnav. See my answer in the thread. There's already a bug reported in lumen-passport. It's not fixed yet as of 23rd of october 2017 but they're working on it.

Comment: Yeah. Seen just now. I rectified the error so that the devs with old repo shall solve it without upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

i think is `$callback->router->group`

Comment: Could yoy please give more explanation with the relevant codes?

Answer (score 0):

Look at fresh lumen project `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

Lumen changed the way to define routes. So, use the new way.

- Old: `$app->group`
- New: `$app->route->group`

Refer [Lumen 5.5 - Route Group](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups)